# Sinatra app in Docker failing to execute 'mysql'?

Tags: mysql, ruby, docker, activerecord, sinatra

This is my first real foray into Docker, and I'm a bit stuck at getting MySQL to play nicely with my app and I'm out of ideas on the why. I'm running the ruby:2.7.6 docker image which uses Debian. I'm trying to setup my database but I'm running into a MySQL issue.

```
➜  cx-core git:(master) ✗ docker compose run api bundle exec rake db:schema:load
[+] Running 2/0
 ⠿ Container cx-core-db-1     Running                                    0.0s
 ⠿ Container cx-core-redis-1  Running                                    0.0s
Starting backup.
Starting backup.
rake aborted!
failed to execute: `mysql`
Please check the output above for any errors and make sure that `mysql` is installed in your PATH and has proper permissions.
```

When running this command below, I am able to access the db with the credentials in my env vars. So, I'm guessing the mistake is somewhere in my docker-compose?

```
➜  cx-core git:(master) ✗ docker exec -it b773c7b1f960 mysql -u cx_core -p 
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 10
Server version: 8.0.28 MySQL Community Server - GPL

Copyright (c) 2000, 2022, Oracle and/or its affiliates.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

database.yml

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5
  username: <%= ENV['DB_USER'] || 'cx_core' %>
  password: <%= ENV['DB_PASS'] || 'cx_core' %>
  host: <%= ENV['DB_HOST'] || 'db' %>
  port: 3306

development:
  <<: *default
  database: cx_core_dev

test:
  <<: *default
  database: cx_core_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: cx_core_prod
```

dockerfile

```
FROM ruby:2.7.6

RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential mariadb-server mariadb-client gnupg

RUN gem install bundler

ENV GEM_HOME="/usr/local/bundle"
ENV PATH $GEM_HOME/bin:$GEM_HOME/gems/bin:$PATH

ENV APP_HOME /app
RUN mkdir $APP_HOME
WORKDIR $APP_HOME

COPY Gemfile* ./

COPY ["config.ru", "Gemfile", "Gemfile.lock", "Rakefile", "./"]
COPY /app /app
COPY config/ config/
COPY db/ db/
COPY lib/ lib/
COPY rakelib/ rakelib/
COPY bin/ bin/

EXPOSE 3000
```

docker-compose

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  api:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - bundle_path:/usr/local/bundle/ # New
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    environment:
      - DB_HOST=db
      - DB_USER=cx_core
      - DB_NAME=cx_core
      - DB_PASSWORD=cx_core
    expose:
      - 3000
    command: bundle exec puma -p 3000
    # entrypoint: ["./bin/start_dev.sh"]
    networks:
      - sinatra

  db:
    image: mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=cx_core_dev
      - MYSQL_USER=cx_core
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=cx_core
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=cx_core
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    expose:
      - '3306'
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - sinatra

  redis:
    image: 'redis:4.0-alpine'
    command: redis-server --requirepass yourpassword
    volumes:
      - 'redis:/data'

volumes:
  redis:
  bundle_path: # New
  db_data:

networks:
  sinatra: 
    driver: bridge
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're missing step with `bundle install` in your Dockerfile.

Try to add this:

```
COPY Gemfile* ./
RUN mkdir -p ~/.ssh && ssh-keyscan -t rsa github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
RUN --mount=type=ssh bundle install --jobs 2
```

before the line `COPY ["config.ru", "Gemfile", "Gemfile.lock", "Rakefile", "./"]` in your Dockerfile.